# Creating a force directed graph in Babylon.js

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I am attempting to create a force directed graph in my Babylon.js project and was wondering if anyone had suggestions as to how I should go about that. I am looking into the barycentric method and the Barnes-Hut method but am wondering if there are any simpler ways of doing so (such as how it is done in d3.js by typing d3.layout.force) or if I should continue on with one of those methods above. I need to add the nodes on top of a plane within a 3D area but the y values of the nodes will remain constant so it is more of a 2D problem.

I also looked into Springy (http://getspringy.com/) but I am not sure if it would be possible to implement that into Babylon.js due to the 3D nature of Babylon.

If anybody has a suggestion to solve this problem I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would break this problem into multiple pieces.

Wrangle the data using an off-the-shelf algorithm into coordinates, then feed the coordinates into Babylon.

A really cheesy way to do it would be to let d3-force do its magic in a hidden SVG, then feed the graph data into Babylon.

Yes, it's a hack, but it would seem to be fast and easy!